# preg_replace and date

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I want to remove all `-` and `/` characters in a date string. Can someone give me a hand?

Here is what I have but it doesn't work.

```
preg_replace('/','',$date);
preg_replace('-','',$date);
```

Also, is there a way to group these two expressions together so I don't have to have 2 preg_replaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `$date = str_replace(aray('/','-'),'',$date);` It's also much faster.

Comment: Thanks ts. THat works. I'll give you the credit here in 4 minutes as it won't let me accept prior to that

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a regex, use a 'translate' method. In PHP, that would be [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

```
strtr( $date, '/-', '' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You need to take a closer look at the examples of `$pattern` in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Here's an example using `preg_replace()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?
$date = "2009/08/07";
echo "Before: ${date}\n";
$date = preg_replace('/[-\/]/', '', $date);
echo "After: ${date}\n";
$date = "2009-08-07";
echo "Before: ${date}\n";
$date = preg_replace('/[-\/]/', '', $date);
echo "After: ${date}\n";
?>


% ./test.php 
Before: 2009/08/07
After: 20090807
Before: 2009-08-07
After: 20090807
```

Answer (score 0):

`[/\-]` is the most efficient, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are replacing one character with another character, a regex based solution is an overkill. You can just use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) as:

```
$edited_date = str_replace(array('/','-'),'',$date);
```

Now what was wrong with your `preg_replace` ?

`preg_replace` expects the regex to be surrounded by a pair of delimiters. So this should have worked:

```
$edited_date = preg_replace('#-#','',$date);
```

Also as `str_replace`, `preg_replace` also accepts arrays, so you can do:

```
$from = array('#/#','#-#');
$to = '';
$edited_date = preg_replace($from,$to,$date);
```

Also you can combine the two patterns to be removed in a single regex as:

```
$edited_date = preg_replace('#-|/#','',$date);
```